# What's the difference between rejecting a pixel at early depth and simply returning?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I know that it's said that the early z or depth test of the graphics pipeline is better than running the pixel/fragment shader, but what about if your fragment shader simply returns as its first statement? What would be the difference in performance in this case? The rasterizer I guess can decide not to interpolate any of the values coming in declared at the top of the shader, or any others that it does. Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 2):

Fragment shaders must write to the declared output fragment colors, or the value of the unwritten outputs is undefined. Your counter example of just returning doesn't work. You could use a `discard`, but that causes other problems.

> What would be the difference in performance in this case?

The shader performance is the least of your potential performance problems. The main issue is that without depth testing you're reliant on software doing a perfect back-to-front sort of incoming triangles (including intersecting ones) to ensure correct visibility. The entire point of depth testing is to avoid the need for sorted geometry, and the performance impact of losing that would be huge even if the fragment shader cost is small.

Assuming you avoid that, I'd still expect the rasterizer to be faster. It's most likely fixed-function dedicated hardware that runs in parallel to the shader core, and there are more useful things for the shader core to be doing than software condition checks. In addition, there are normally lots of tricks to rapidly reject large regions of occluded pixels or even entire triangles, so the fixed-function hardware isn't even looking at samples individually unless it really needs to, e.g. hier-zs testing.

Comment: It's undefined if a fragment colour isn't written? What if you have multiple render targets/framebuffers, say 4, and you only want to render to the fourth one conditionally? That would force you to change pipeline objects and render pass?

Comment: Change pipeline for sure, it's the  equivalent of glDrawBuffers() in OpenGL/OpenGL ES.

Comment: Could you point me to anything that says that it's undefined to return from a fragment shader? Or that all attachments/render targets must be written to?

Comment: For the old `gl_FragColor` behaviour the wording is "If subsequent fixed functionality consumes fragment color and an execution of a fragment shader does not write a value to gl_FragColor then the fragment color consumed is undefined."

Comment: Given _anything_ after the shader, including framebuffer update, counts as "subsequent fixed functionality" it's undefined. Can't yet find an equivalent wording in the ESSL 3 spec, but I'd assume the same to hold.

Comment: ES3: "Writing to a user-defined output variable specifies the value of the fragment color it is explicitly or implicitly bound to. Any fragment colors which are not written by the fragment shader are undefined."

Comment: What do you do if you want to discard a pixel dependent on alpha threshold? Discard isn't good enough? you need to write to gl_fragColour? I don't get it you don't even need to write to gl_FragColour if you've got multiple render targets, you specify which render target by writing to the named image resource that you declare

Comment: So that statement is saying that if I have multiple render targets/attachments and I don't write to one then it's undefined? What is ES3? Is it like GLSL?

Comment: Discard is fine. Your question didn't mention doing a discard, it said "return". ES3 is the OpenGL ES 3.0 shader language spec. If you want to ask a different question please create a new one.

Comment: @solidpixel: "*Fragment shaders must write to the declared output fragment colors, or the behavior is undefined.*" That's only true of the outputs you don't write to. The value of those which you do write to is defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ack sloppy language on my part. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Measure it and see? :)

The theory works a bit like this. Let's assume we have a few vertex shader outputs:

```cpp
out vec2 uv_coord;
out vec3 light_dir;
out vec3 eye_pos;
out vec3 normal;

void main() {
   // the special case
   gl_Position = map * in_vertex;

   // the custom cases
   uv_coord = something;
   light_dir = something;
   eye_pos = something;
   normal = something;
}
```

You'll note that when we use those in the fragment shader, the position is nowhere to be seen *(well, technically it's available as gl_FragCoord I guess)*

```cpp
in vec2 uv_coord;
in vec3 light_dir;
in vec3 eye_pos;
in vec3 normal;

void main() {

   // here's my fragment shader rejection
   if(some_condition) 
      discard;
   else {
      do_some_lighting_calculation();
   }
}
```

In theory, in order to reject a pixel via the depth test, you should only need to interpolate the `gl_Position` outputs from the vertex shader, which are then tested against the depth buffer. If the depth test fails, there is no point in interpolating the additional params *(e.g. uv_coord, normal, etc)*

So, if the depth test fails, we don't need to interpolate uv_coord/normal etc.
However, if the depth test passes, we ***do*** need to interpolate those additional params prior to executing the fragment shader. Even if you return on the first line of the shader, those parameters must have been interpolated.

Then we get into hardware guesstimation territory. It's theoretically possible to implement a depth test in one of two ways. Either we build specific circuitry that is optimised specifically for the depth test, or we build a more general purpose processor, and perform the depth test as a software routine. You would assume that in the case of the former, depth testing circuitry should outperform the more general fragment shader.

That's the theory anyway. YMMV. I can imagine ways that driver writers *could* optimise the early return from the fragment shader such that it becomes almost as fast as the depth test rejection. I suspect it may therefore be a case where you'd need to benchmark a selection of hardware to know the performance difference for certain.

It is however safe to assume that rejecting a fragment early in the pipeline is always going to be the fastest option. Rejecting from within a fragment shader can never be more performant! *(but it could in theory be reasonably close - YMMV)*

The exact difference in performance between the two is very much going to be hardware/driver specific. Measure it and see? :)

Comment: Do you know anything about not being able to return from the fragment shader? And that the colour output must be written? As said in the other answer? I never knew about this, and it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Do you mean 'discard' ?