# How can end a fragment shader without calling discard?

Tags: graphics, glsl

Let's say I want to test the alpha in the fragment shader and if it's below a certain amount just exit the fragment shader. A fragment shader needs to be run, unlike for drawing solid (non alpha tested and non alpha blended) geometry. I want to discard the pixel but discard also doesn't write the depth. I want the depth write to be maintained and exit the program. Apparently calling return from the fragment shader without writing all the attachments at that pixel the value of that pixel is left undefined. See the comments in this question:
[What's the difference between rejecting a pixel at early depth and simply returning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616392/whats-the-difference-between-rejecting-a-pixel-at-early-depth-and-simply-return/76617698?noredirect=1#76617698)

Answer (score 1):

For the specific use case of wanting depth but not wanting color update, you can specify a shader with forced early fragment tests:

`layout(early_fragment_tests) in;`

... and then `discard` in the shader as normal when you determine you don't want to keep it. This only works if you don't have other side-effects that forced early tests would break, it's not 100% general purpose.

Comment: Is this only in opengl? Or also in Vulkan?

Comment: Vulkan supports this too.

Comment: If the depth test state is set to write it'll write the depth if it passes, right? What's the use of that? I mean, if you want to do alpha cutout.

Comment: As per your question "I want the depth write to be maintained and exit the program." This does what you asked for. I have no idea why you want do it, it was your question, not mine.

Comment: Obviously if you want to do alpha-cut-out and _not_ write depth for discarded fragments, then you cannot use `layout(early_fragment_tests)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of ideas, but none of them is perfect.

Probably the best solution is something like this:

```c
if(color.a < alphaThreshold) {
    outputColor = vec4(0.0);
} else {
    // continue your algorithm
}
```

This requires you to enable alpha blending which has overhead, but if the alpha value is below a certain amount, you just write a color with 0.0 alpha value, so the color won't change in the render target, but the depth value will be updated.

---

Another variant of this, without enabling alpha blending is just copying the render target to a new texture and when the alpha value is too low, you just write the color value from the previous render target.

```c
if(color.a < alphaThreshold) {
    outputColor = texture(previousRenderTarget, gl_FragCoord.xy);
} else {
    // continue your algorithm
}
```

With this solution, you don't have to enable alpha blending, but you need to copy a texture and you need extra texture sampling.

---

Also, with `glColorMaski` or with `glDrawBuffers` you can disable writing to the color attachments, but it only makes sense, if you know, that all alpha values will be low.